# Reference request: Nichols algebras of a braided vector space with a diagonal braiding

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, nichols-algebras

Are there some references of the proof of the following result?

Let $(V, c)$ be a braided vector space over a field $k$ with a basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, where $c$ is a diagonal braiding given by
\begin{align}
c(x_i \otimes x_j) = q^{a_{ij}} x_j \otimes x_i, \quad 0 \neq q \in k.
\end{align} 
If $q$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the Nichols algebra $B(V)$ is given by
\begin{align}
k\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n | ad_c(x_i)^{1-a_{ij}}x_j = 0, \ i \neq j \rangle,
\end{align}
where $ad_c(x_i)(x_j) = x_i x_j - q^{a_{ij}} x_j x_i$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Rosso, Marc. Quantum groups and quantum shuffles. Invent. Math. 133 (1998), no. 2, 399--416. MR1632802?